# fastest way to generate column with random elements based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of ~20M lines

I have a column called `A` that gives me an id (there are ~10K ids in total).
The value of this id defines a random distribution's parameters.
Now I want to generate a column `B`, that is randomly drawn from the distribution that is defined by the value in the column `A`

What is the fastest way to do this? Doing something with `iterrows` or `apply` is extremely slow. Another possiblity is to group by `A`, and generate all my data for each value of A (so I only draw from one distribution). But then I don't end up with a Dataframe but with a "groupBy" object, and I don't know how to go back to having the initial dataframe, plus my new column.

Comment: Try taking a look at [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: sorry I tried this as well, and it's really slow (iterating over every row etc)

Comment: Can you provide a sample code with input/outputs ?

Comment: Also have you checked that [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach is similar to what you were describing, where you generate the samples for each id. On my machine, it appears this would take around 5 minutes to run. I assume you can trivially get the ids.

```
import numpy as np

num_ids = 10000
num_rows = 20000000
ids = np.arange(num_ids)
loc_params = np.random.random(num_ids)
A = np.random.randint(0, num_ids, num_rows)
B = np.zeros(A.shape)

for idx in ids:
    A_idxs = A == idx
    B[A_idxs] = np.random.normal(np.sum(A_idxs), loc_params[idx])
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty vague, but how would this work for you?

```
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda row: distribution(row.A), axis=1)
```

**Editing from question edits (apply is too slow)**:

You could create a mapping dictionary for the 10k ids to their generated value, then do something like

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(dictionary)
```

I'm unsure if this will be faster than apply, but it will require fewer calls to your random distribution generator

Comment: sorry I tried this as well, and it's really slow (iterating over every row etc)

Comment: Check my update, I'm not sure how well it will work for you though